# 3 Android GPS Questions

Tags: android, gps

1) For some reason, the longitude and latitude are slightly different after storing  them. For example, when i first find them, they are:
25.171057657111998 and 35.013447496224636 but after I store them , they are 
25.1710586547852 and 35.0134468078613. Why is this happening? I store them as floats in an sqlite database, retrieve them with Cursor.getFloat, and print them with String.format of 13 digit accuracy.Can this difference affect the end results in a significant way? I am working with distances <100m (328 feet)

2)I am trying to find the center of a location cluster. Here 
http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html
method C says I can just take a simple average if I work with <400km. Has anyone tried it? Is it working? Or should I go for the first, more accurate method?

3) After finding the center, do I need anything else to create a new location object for distance purposes?

Comment: You'd probably be better off breaking up the questions.

Comment: anything past 5 decimal places for a GPS point is pretty useless unless you need some crazy accuracy for whatever reason because you are talking about inches at that point

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you may store longitude and latitude in your sqlite database by this way:

longitude*10^10 , latitude*10^10

when you get them you will divide them by 10^10.

because with 5 decimal is accurate

Comment: actually these results are multimplied and divided by 10^12. Without multiplication, they are equally bad